# SQLCE Compact Database Multi-User over Network

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, multi-user

My Application was moved to a shared Network to offer the Clients a Folder with the Program. In this Folder is the SQLCE Compact Database too.

I only need to read from a Database. In my Opinion should the standalone in read-only mode not beeing blocked from the current User, but it is. This blocking access is in my opinion only useful if multiple users try to write...

Is there a way to get a SQLCE Compact Database ready to run for multi-user over a Network?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately The short answer is no. SQLCE is single user/instance by design. However you can create a service that load your db and allow your program instances to read and write in the db through the service. The other option is to modify your app to create a local copy of the db and sync the changes using a SQL server. what doesn't make any sense since your app is in a shared folder, so why don't migrate to a true DB like sql server?
SQLCE and SQL server are full compatible, basicaly you just need to change the connection string.

Comment: Because the Application is a offline used Application and has to run without Internet. But there is a good point: I think i copy the database from the systemfolder to the Windows-Specialfolder (Appdata) and change the path from the Database from |DataDirectory| to the  SpecialFolder. So every user has its own pulled Database locally.

Comment: With a local SQL server you still able to run the application without internet, or you mean without any connection like in field operations?